# añadir ext a mi certificado

Tags: java

Podrían ayudarme, tengo mi CA interno dentro de la oficina y me funciona bien. pero tengo un problema al crear un certificado *SAN* para `Java`. Estoy usando la siguiente sintaxis:

```
keytool -certreq -alias proxev01 -ext SAN=dns:ev01.pepe.com,dns:mv01.pepe.com -keystore proxev01.jks -file proxev01.csr
```

Luego al firmar en mi CA:

```
openssl x509 -sha256 -req -in proxev01.csr -CA /etc/pki/CA/certs/pepeCA.crt -CAkey /etc/pki/CA/private/pepeCA.key -CAserial /etc/pki/CA/serial.txt -out proxev01.crt -days 730.
```

Me genera el certificado correctamente del nombre común, pero lo de las *SAN* no. Según leo la sintaxis de `Keytool` es correcta es `-ext SAN=dns`..... podrían ayudarme.

Gracias.